# How can I download the source XML file of an RSS feed in cocoa touch?

Tags: xml, cocoa-touch, ios, download, offline-mode

I'm looking for how to download the source XML file of an RSS feed in cocoa touch to make an offline mode for my XML parser app.
Does anyone know how to do it?
My app is designed for iOS 4.2.1 (not earlier) and i'm running XCode 3.2.5.

Thanks you for all your future answers to my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSURLConnection` to download the data and then persist it somewhere.